# Applescript error "invalid key form" when run

Tags: applescript

I tried to run this applescript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file contents "/Users/xx/Desktop/xxxx/" to POSIX file "/USB/" with replacing
    delete POSIX file contents "/Users/felix/Desktop/xxxx/"
    empty trash
end tell
```

but every time an error message appears saying:

> Invalid key form.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `contents`. This should work.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set src to POSIX file "/Users/xx/Desktop/test.tmp"
    set dst to POSIX file "/USB/"
    duplicate src to dst with replacing
end tell
```

Comment: now when I run it, applescript editor throws up this message: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.

Comment: this one:    duplicate src to dst with replacing

Comment: I did have some problems with the target being a symbolic link but didn't find a solution yet. I got a different error message, though.